# How can I remove a device from btsync?

Tags: synchronization

In the [BitTorrent Sync](https://www.getsync.com/) web interface, there's a GUI for managing folders and devices. However, I seem to have accidentally linked the same Nexus 5 twice. How can I remove (or unlink) one of these devices?

[image: screenshot]